# How to force hyperref to reference only \cite and not \citeauthor or \citeyear?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, natbib

I would like `hyperref` to make links only when I use `\cite` and not with `\citeyear` and `\citeauthor`. Here is an example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{Wysocki1960} has shown something interesting in \citeyear{Wysocki1960} \cite{Wysocki1960}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

With the .bib file :

```
@article{Wysocki1960,
annote = {cited By (since 1996) 27},
author = {Wysocki, J.J.},
journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
number = {3},
pages = {571--578},
title = {{Effect of temperature on photovoltaic solar energy conversion}},
volume = {31},
year = {1960}
}
```

In the output, I want only the [1] to appear as a link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The hyperlinks are set by the macro `\NAT@hyper@#1` defined in `natbib.sty`. Using `etoolbox` you can hook into the low-level citation command `\NAT@citexnum` to make `\NAT@hyper@` do nothing for non-numeric citations. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\NAT@citexnum}{\@ifnum{\NAT@ctype>\z@}{\let\NAT@hyper@\relax}{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Reading, Mass.},
  year = {1994}}
@Book{adams,
  title = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author = {Douglas Adams},
  series = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year = {1980}}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cmd{citeauthor}: \citeauthor{adams}, \citeauthor{companion} \\
\cmd{cite}: \cite{adams}, \cite{companion} \\
\cmd{citeyear}: \citeyear{adams}, \citeyear{companion} \\
\cmd{citet}: \citet{adams}, \citet[see][p. 20]{adams} \\
multi-\cmd{citet}: \citet{companion,adams} \\
\cmd{citep}: \citep{adams}, \citep[see][p. 20]{companion} \\
multi-\cmd{citep}: \citep{companion,adams} \\
\cmd{citetext}, \cmd{citealp}: \citetext{see \citealp{companion}, or even better \citealp{adams}}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get only question marks when I compile your code. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You probably need to rerun latex. I compiled the above document with pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex.

Comment: If I put the jobname.bib in a separate file, it works. Thanks!

Comment: The problem may be related to this new question I asked concerning a specific reference : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67645/problem-with-hyperref-not-linking-a-reference

Comment: @jul059 I already fixed the solution here. Does it work for you now?

Comment: @Audrey The solution here works for me.